# How to get items from sys_categories

Tags: typo3, categories, extbase, sys

what is the best way to get the items from categories.

I have a project with approx 40 categories and in total 3000 items and 4 level.

I found a way from TYPO3 self by collections but i must add them to the category manual?

I saw that the TYPO3 blog extension takes another way by an extra column "posts" and a objectstorage in the model categories. So not necessary to add the items / posts.

Somehow the second way like the blog does, sounds nicer but is this performant, when i have a list of 3 categories with each 4 to 5 subcategories and each approx 100 to 250 items?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Do you want to get subcategories or all related records for one specified category? for the latter i have written below a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

you could build a query and get all related items yourself from the DB.

```
// get QueryBuilder for table 'sys_category_record_mm'
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('sys_category_record_mm');

// query the table
$result = $queryBuilder
    ->select('uid_foreign,tablenames')
    ->from('sys_category_record_mm')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('uid_local', $uidOfYourCategory))
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```

Now, `$result` is an array with all childs of the category wit the id `$uidOfYourCategory`. This array you can use to get the items from their repos.

If you only want items from tt_content, or maybe a table named tx_yourtable, you can add an `andWhere` to the query lik this:

```
$result = $queryBuilder
    ->select('uid_foreign,tablenames')
    ->from('sys_category_record_mm')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('uid_local', $uidOfYourCategory))
    ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('tablenames', 'tx_yourtable'))
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```